# How to save hashmap values to sharedpreference?

Tags: android, hashmap, sharedpreferences

I have a hashmap that is this:

```
static final ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> tasklist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
```

I want to store the contents of the `hashMap` arraylist to `sharedpreference`.

How can i do that ? And also, how do I retrieve the values afterwards?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I used this kind of thing in my project, It might help you hopefully :)

Here is how to save them:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
  "My Preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = prefs.edit();
prefsEditor.putStringSet("myStringSet", set);
prefsEditor.commit();
```

And here is how to get them:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
  "My Preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
set = prefs.getStringSet("myStringSet", null);
```

Comment: how do you extract the content if for example the contents are like this?

["{action= some text, task= some text}", "{action= some text 2, task= some text 2 }" ]

Comment: @user3325919 So let me get this straight. The kind of data you are using is like key-value? Where you have a key, with a value corresponding to it? Because you have written action=some text and task = sometext. I am presuming "sometext" is of type string. What type is "action" and "task"?

Comment: @Ogen : Your way only apply for `String` not apply for `Object` right?

Comment: @HuyTower Yes. If you want it to apply to object, you must change `<String>` to `<Object>`.

Comment: If so, `prefsEditor.putStringSet("myStringSet", set);` This code gets error. I already did it and saw error. Any recommend?

Comment: @HuyTower Can you tell me the code that you used to declare your `set` variable

Comment: Sorry not explained clearly. This one `Set<Beacon> set = new HashSet<Beacon>();`. Beacon is model I defined.

Comment: @HuyTower Your `set` variable has to be of type `Set<String>` not `Set<Beacon>`. Because the method is called `putStringSet` not `putBeaconSet`. You can make a set that contains the beacons' UUID as a string and put that into shared preferences. Then when you retrieve the string set, you can find the beacons corresponding to the appropriate UUID.

Comment: @Ogen : No, that is not the way I want. I want `save Hashmap into Shared Preferences`, so I already used the other way more better. And completed now.  Via `ObjectSerializer` class from `org.apache.pig:pig` maven. Thank you too.

Comment: @HuyTower Oh yeah I forgot about serializing the beacon to a string and storing that. Good idea! :D

Answer (score 0):

I think the right way is saving your hashmap in database. You can read about sqlite here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

I store Java objects in Shared Preferences by serializing them to JSON using the GSON framework. I prefer JSON because it is human readable, and my app already deals with JSON when making HTTP calls to the back end service. I think I have just the right amount of complexity to not have to create/maintain a SQL Lite database.

One of the more interesting uses I have had for this is to maintain an application wide upload queue. My app allows uploading video and images to the back end servers. I track them in status lists inside the shared preferences. Any activity that needs this data can read from these "queues" instead of passing the data all over the place.